# exibir resultado array dentro da mensagem phpmailer

Tags: array, for, sintaxe, phpmailer

Boa noite pessoal, preciso exibir os resultados de um array em um corpo de mensagem `phpmailer`, logo, enviar o mesmo por e-mail. Meu código de envio está funcionando e fiz vários testes, o e-mail chega perfeitamente, menos o resultado do array, e quando chega, só vem um item, o primeiro, os demais não, geralmente 5 a 10 itens.

Testei o array com envio a uma página PHP "normal" e o array funciona, os itens são exibidos na tela, chego a crer que seja sintaxe, pois o código é o mesmo com exceção das aspas simples ou duplas. Resumindo, como posso colocar o `for` dentro do corpo `$mensagem` para chegar a tabela por e-mail?

Segue o código:

```
$mensagem = "
<table border='1' cellspacing='0' width='70%' style='font-family: Roboto-Regular, arial, serif; font-size: 15px; color: #6f4500'>
<tr>
<th>Itens</th> <th>ID do Produto</th> <th>Código</th> <th>Tipo</th> <th>Produto</th><th>Preço</th><th>Quantidade</th><th>Valor total</th>
</tr>
        ".$idProd = $_POST['arrayidProd']."
        ".$cod = $_POST['arraycod']."
        ".$tipo = $_POST['arraytipo']."
        ".$produto = $_POST['arrayproduto']."
        ".$preco = $_POST['arraypreco']."
        ".$qtd = $_POST['arrayqtd']."
        ".$total = $_POST['arraytotal']."
        
    for($i = 0; $i < count($idProd); $i++) {
    <td></td><td>".$idProd[$i]."</td><td>".$cod[$i]."</td><td>".$tipo[$i]."</td><td>".$produto[$i]."</td><td>".$preco[$i]."</td><td>".$qtd[$i]."</td><td>".$total[$i]."</td></tr>
    }
</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

[Teste aqui](https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/94ff44bb25f5677888644cce7da222c05a282888)

1. Primeiro passo - recupere os valores do POST

   ```
   $idProd = $_POST['arrayidProd'];
   $cod = $_POST['arraycod'];
   $tipo = $_POST['arraytipo'];
   $produto = $_POST['arrayproduto'];
   $preco = $_POST['arraypreco'];
   $qtd = $_POST['arrayqtd'];
   $total = $_POST['arraytotal'];
   ```
2. Segundo passo - realize o loop concatenando os valores em uma variável

   ```
   for($i = 0; $i < count($idProd); $i++) {
   $linhas .= ("<tr><td></td><td>".$idProd[$i]."</td><td>".$cod[$i]."</td><td>".$tipo[$i]."</td><td>".$produto[$i]."</td><td>".$preco[$i]."</td><td>".$qtd[$i]."</td><td>".$total[$i]."</td></tr>");
   }
   ```
3. Crie a mensagem

   ```
   $mensagem = "
   <table border='1' cellspacing='0' width='70%' style='font-family: Roboto-Regular, arial, serif; font-size: 15px; color: #6f4500'>
   <tr>
   <th>Itens</th> <th>ID do Produto</th> <th>Código</th> <th>Tipo</th> <th>Produto</th><th>Preço</th><th>Quantidade</th><th>Valor total</th>
   </tr>".$linhas."
   </table>";
   ```

**Código completo**

```
<?php
        
    $idProd = $_POST['arrayidProd'];
    $cod = $_POST['arraycod'];
    $tipo = $_POST['arraytipo'];
    $produto = $_POST['arrayproduto'];
    $preco = $_POST['arraypreco'];
    $qtd = $_POST['arrayqtd'];
    $total = $_POST['arraytotal'];    
 
    for($i = 0; $i < count($idProd); $i++) {
        $linhas .= ("<tr><td></td><td>".$idProd[$i]."</td><td>".$cod[$i]."</td><td>".$tipo[$i]."</td><td>".$produto[$i]."</td><td>".$preco[$i]."</td><td>".$qtd[$i]."</td><td>".$total[$i]."</td></tr>");
    }
 
    $mensagem = "
    <table border='1' cellspacing='0' width='70%' style='font-family: Roboto-Regular, arial, serif; font-size: 15px; color: #6f4500'>
    <tr>
    <th>Itens</th> <th>ID do Produto</th> <th>Código</th> <th>Tipo</th> <th>Produto</th><th>Preço</th><th>Quantidade</th><th>Valor total</th>
    </tr>".$linhas."
    </table>";
 
?>
```